# NaN when trying to multiply a json value with local variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm trying to change a JSON value from an object from seconds to hours. The problem is, when I try to multiply it with my local constant to convert it, it returns a NaN value.

i've already tried using JSON.stringify(Json_value) and it didn't help

```
const secToHours = '0,000277778';
const hourTime = secToHours*JSON.stringify(jsonData.duration);
logs = []
logs.push({"id":jsonData.id,"key":jsonData.issueKey, "date": dateFormatted, "duration": hourTime})
                var array = [{user:jsonData.userId, logs:logs}];
                console.log(array[0]);

This is the console output:
{
  user: 'XXXXX',
  logs: [ { id: XXXXX, key: 'XX-X', date: '2019-7-3', duration: NaN } ]
}
```

I don't know why it's returning a NaN value for the multiplication, and if i print the values separated, they return the respective const value and the json data.

Comment: secToHours is currently a string, 0.0000277778 would be the correct value (note the `.` and the missing `'`

Comment: well, you can't multiply strings

Comment: @GrafiCode: Sure you can. `"10" * "10" === 100; // true`

Comment: @ziggywiggy D'oh! You're correct,  Do vars self cast to numbers when multiplying?

Comment: @GrafiCode: Yes, all values in JS will get converted to a number when using arithmetic operators (except when `+` does concatenation).

Comment: @ziggywiggy Thanks for the explanation, I've always used `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`

Comment: @GrafiCode: That would definitely be the preferred approach. Better to be explicit than to rely on implicit conversions by the engine, IMO.

Comment: ```let secToHours = '0,000277778';
        let jsonValue = JSON.stringify(jsonData.duration);
        secToHours = parseFloat(secToHours.replace(',', '.'));
        jsonValue = parseFloat(jsonValue.replace(',', '.'));
        const hourTime = secToHours * jsonValue;```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0,000277778`   is not a valid JS number - your local convention may use comma's as a decimal point, but JS expects a dot.

You don't need/want to use `JSON.stringify` on  `jsonData.duration`  though I can't see from this if you need to manipulate it in some other way - where is it declared/what value does it have on line 2?

Comment: Thank you, I tried it without the JSON.Stringify and it worked just as fine